# PyQT как описать функцию смены цвета кнопки по условию?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть фронт сделанный на виджетах **PyQT**

В этом коде описывется запуск браузера и функции эмуляции кликов внутри страницы, вызываемые нажатиями кнопок. Для упрощения тут порезал JS скрипты и количество кнопок

```
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from interface import Ui_MainWindow
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    driver.get(url) 

    class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):  #связываем функции с UI кнопками
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.NoAdress)
            self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.SpecTransp)
            self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.NoSvetofor)

        def NoAdress(self):          #функция для кнопки 1
            driver.execute_script('''some js code 1''')

        def SpecTransp(self): #функция для кнопки 2
            driver.execute_script('''some js code 2''')

        def NoSvetofor(self): #функция для кнопки 3
            driver.execute_script('''some js code 3''')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        window = ExampleApp()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
```

Втыкание этого кода в одну из функций кнопок меняет ее цвет

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: red; color: white;}')
```

Как описать функцию, которая будет менять цвет одной из кнопок в зависимости от заданного условия? Т.е. допустим если x == 1: то button_1 выделяется красным, если x = 2: то кнопка 2 выделяется красным, x == 3: button_3 и т.д.

Comment: `self.buttons = [self.button, self.button_2, self.button_3]`. Далее обращаетесь к каждой кнопке как к элементу списка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример варианта решения предоставленного в комментарии @МихаилМуругов :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttons = []

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(0, 5)
        self.spinBox.setValue(4)
        self.spinBox.setPrefix(" Измените цвет button:  ")
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(True)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged[int].connect(self.qspinbox_value_changed)
        lay.addWidget(self.spinBox)

        for i in range(0, 6):
            textButton = 'pushButton_{}'.format(i)
            button = QPushButton(textButton, clicked=lambda _, text=textButton: print(text))
            lay.addWidget(button)
            self.buttons.append(button)

        self.buttons[4].setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: red; color: white;}')

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def qspinbox_value_changed(self, new_value):    
        for i, btn in enumerate(self.buttons):
            if i == new_value:
                btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: red; color: white;}')
            else: 
                btn.setStyleSheet('')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    default_font = QFont()
    default_font.setPointSize(15)
    app.setFont(default_font)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, пример помог